# Formatting the output in console.log in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want the output displayed in webconsole using console.log in a table format is it possible to print it. For example i have two variables x and y whose values keep changing. Can i print this variables in a table in console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

```
console.dir(someObject);
```

Make sure your output is object.

Also you can find some other console commands at firebug website http://getfirebug.com/logging

For google chrome see official [docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Comment: What browser do you use and what debugging tool?

Comment: i am using firefox and this code is actually written in add-on builder. I am not using firebug

Comment: Well I think this depends on environment. You need to see docs of addon-builder

Answer (score 0):

```
console.table([{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:"foo", b:false, c:undefined}]);
console.table([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]);
```